# React js: How to set props in JSX components which store in variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I already define an component:

```
class Co extends React.Component {
    render = () => {
        const name = this.props.name;
        return (
            <p>Hello, my name is {name}</p>
        )
    }
}
```

and store it in an variable:

```
const co = <Co />;
```

How can I set the component's props with the variable? Would `co.props.set` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand you don't want to render your component in JSX syntax but with your stored variable. You can have a look at `React.cloneElement`. This should do what you want:

`{React.cloneElement(co, {name: 'hans'})}`

See: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement

Answer (score 0):

You can set props as usual

```
<Co name="Name"/>
```

If element is child of some component then you can use React.cloneElement()

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render = () => {
        const name = this.props.name;
        return (
            <SomeComp><Co/></SomeComp>
        )
    }
}
class SomeComp extends React.Component {
    render = () => {
        const name = this.props.name;
        return (
            <SomeComp>{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {name:"Name"})}</SomeComp>
        )
    }
}
```